# Dynamic SQL Server Query to Fill DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello I need to do the follow query in SQL Server to fill and Datatable.

In my case I have 3 tables:

```
1 - Users
2 - Process
3 - Status
```

Users

```
id, name
```

Process

```
id, cod_user, cod_status
```

Status

```
id, status
```

I need to make an query that return the follow table:

> ```
> User.Name | Status.Created | Status.Opened | Status.Finalized 
> Tom               50              30                20
> Roger             22              33                44
> Kris              11              09                05
> ```

And then, I have to return this table to fill and datatable.

Thanks...

Comment: You should go with [**`Joins`**](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm)

Comment: Which part of those three steps (querying, returing table, filling datatable) are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm stuck querying. How I build this query?

Comment: You want to fill the view? Are you searching for InsteadOf Triggers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: perhaps maybe an view or build a directly query.

Comment: Sorry one little question, I've got already what you said, but what is the value of the Status columns? Do they contain counts or they are some Status codes? I think you wanna show the Count of one specific state per user. Yeah?

Comment: Yeah it is. I have an table that contains all status then I have to count all processes for all users with specified status.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to `PIVOT` the data, you can use something like this if you know the values of `status` to transform:

```
select name, [Created], [Opened], [Finalized]
from
(
    select u.name,
        s.status
    from users u
    left join process p
        on u.id = p.cod_user
    left join status s
        on p.cod_status = s.id
) src
pivot
(
    count(status)
    for status in ([Created], [Opened], [Finalized])
) piv
```

If you have an unknown number of statuses to turn into columns, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(status) 
                    from status
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select u.name,
                    s.status
                from users u
                left join process p
                    on u.id = p.cod_user
                left join status s
                    on p.cod_status = s.id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(status)
                for status in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

If you don't have access to the `PIVOT` function, then you can replicate it using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select u.name,
    sum(case when s.status = 'created' then 1 else 0 end) created,
    sum(case when s.status = 'opened' then 1 else 0 end) opened,
    sum(case when s.status = 'finalized' then 1 else 0 end) finalized
from users u
left join process p
    on u.id = p.cod_user
left join status s
    on p.cod_status = s.id
group by u.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to show one record per User, with one column per Status, and the columns contain the count of records in the Process table with that status for that user?

If that's correct, then you want to use a Pivot Table.